# How to check if a value is in a interval of hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to check if a value in a cell is inside an interval of hours like
*Is 22:00 in interval 23:00-05:00?*

Considering that in B2 I have a value of `21:00`, in C2 I need to check if that value is inside or outside of the interval `23:00 - 05:00`.

How could I do this?

I checked many functions but without success. One of those is:

```
=IF(AND(B2>=TIME(23;0;0); B2<TIME(5;0;0)); "INSIDE"; "OUTSIDE")
```

Using this formula I always get "OUTSIDE", even when I change the value to be in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this formula.

```
=IF(B2<>"",IF(OR(B2>=TIME(23,0,0), B2<=TIME(5,0,0)), "INSIDE", "OUTSIDE"),"")
```

[image]

should meet your criteria
in addition, you can change the time you want by changing `23` or `5`
and added the function if cell is empty to leave it empty

with Italian settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunately is not working on my side (using in italian). With your formula i got error analysis formula.
I changed with this
=IF(B5<>"";IF(OR(B5>=TIME(23;0;0); B5<=TIME(5;0;0)); "INSIDE"; "OUTSIDE");"")
and i got always INSIDE

Comment: I found the cause of the error
formula works fine :)

I changed the regional settings of the sheet to Italy and the time zone to Rome, you probably have the same, the time in the sheet you have to enter is '21.00' instead of '21:00' I don't know why you have it like that but if you want to change it, I recommend changing the settings in the time zone sheet to e.g. warsaw

1. Click File>Settings
2. Change time zone (GMT+01:00) Warsaw
3. Save the settings

should help

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working now...... !!!